# "Could not reach Firestore backend", multiple Firebase apps, Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm migrating from Realtime Database to Firestore. Because I can't have both a Realtime Database instance and a Firestore instance in the same project, I have to init the Firestore instance manually, rather than have it pick up the `google-services.json` file automatically as part of the build. I've done that like this:

```
    FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setProjectId("***")
            .setApiKey("***")
            .setApplicationId("***")
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://***.firebaseio.com")
            .build();
    FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, firebaseOptions, "dev");
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(firebaseApp);
```

All the values are taken from the `google-services.json` file I downloaded for the new project.

Calling `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()` is fine, but when I later try to get a document, I see this in logcat:

```
W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Firestore backend.
```

The `Task` for a `get()` call to a `Document` has an exception message of:

```
Failed to get document because the client is offline.
```

The device is online, for sure. The new project in the console does NOT have the SHA certificate fingerprints set, because I can't use the same one as for the original project.

What am I missing?

[Edit]

[image: Warning message screenshot]

[image: Error message secreenshot]

Comment: That's not true.  You can have both Realtime Database and Firestore in the same project.  Typically, you don't need to initialize Firebase SDKs at all if you follow the documentation.

Comment: That sounds like an answer Doug ;-)

Comment: From the console UI: "Enabling Cloud Firestore Beta will preclude you from using Cloud Datastore with this project, notably from the associated App Engine app."

Comment: @Eliot Realtime Database != Firestore != Cloud Datastore.  Please confirm the *exact* error message?

Comment: @DougStevenson I realise this - I'm merely pasting from your own UI. Screenshot above in an edit.

Comment: In your question, you said "I can't have both a **Realtime Database** instance and a **Firestore** instance in the same project".  But the error message is saying you can't have both **Cloud Firestore** and **Cloud Datastore** in the same project.  I think you misread the message.  You can definitely have Realtime Database and Firestore in the same project - I do that all the time.

Comment: What the hell is "Cloud Datastore" then? Why do you guys have some many products that sound exactly the same? ;-)

Comment: OK, I see the App Engine and "Cloud Datastore" stuff at https://console.cloud.google.com/ and it's some obsolete stuff we were doing years ago. I'm happy to delete it. But how? For Datastore, I've deleted all the data and disabled writes. For App Engine, I've disabled the application and deleted what I can, but the default service cannot be deleted. I still get the above error message and the "learn more" link goes to a page which explains nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is a little late for the answer. In my case, I had the same problem because I try to test Datastore and I lose the possibility to use Firestore in my project. When I try to create a new project for Firestore,  I have to init the Firestore instance manually and I had the same problem.

In my case, the problem was that one of the parameters of FirebaseOptions was wrong (in my case was project_id because I had put project_number). I had taken all parameters from google_services.json from the new project:

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("X:XXXXXXXX:android:YYYYYYY") // FROM client_info -> mobilesdk_app_id.
            .setApiKey("AIzaXXXXXXXXXXX") // FROM api_key -> current_key
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://XXXXXXX.firebaseio.com") // FROM firebase_url.
            .setProjectId("XXXXXXXX") //FROM project_id
            .setStorageBucket("XXXXXXX.appspot.com") //FROM storage_bucket
            .build();
```

After that everything start to work fine.